# CakePHP 3.x - Associations Error- unable Linking Tables Together

Tags: mysql, associations, cakephp-3.x

i'm trying to Associate 2 tables:`Jobes` and `Types`. the table structure of types is very simple and includes only `id` and `name` ( 1.full-time 2.partial 3.freelance)

Jobs table, in addition to all other fields contains also the foreign key of Types named:`type_id` so Jobs  **belongsTo** Types.
i follow the Cake convention but still the same error:

> Jobs is not associated with Types...

i'v created JobsTable class

```
use Cake\ORM\Table;
class JobsTable extends Table{

    public $name= 'Jobs';

    public function initialize(array $config){
        $this->belongsTo('Types');                            
    }
}
```

declare it in the controller:

```
 <?php

    namespace App\Controller;

    use App\Controller\AppController;

    class JobsController extends AppController

{

        public $name='Jobs';

        public function index(){
            //Get job info
        $jobs =$this->Jobs->find('all')->contain(['Types']);
        $this->set('jobs',$jobs);

        }
    }
```

and then past it to view (index.ctp):

```
<?php foreach ($jobs as $job) : ?>

    <p> <?php echo $job->title; ?> <?php echo $job->types->name; ?></p>

 <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: It's possible that `$this->Jobs` is not what you think it is, but rather just a default Table object. In your index function, check `get_class($this->Jobs)` to make sure that it's the class you expect.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `foreignKey` too.

**JobsTable.php**

```
$this->belongsTo('Types', [
        'foreignKey' => 'type_id'
    ]);
```

**TypesTable.php**

```
$this->hasMany('Jobs', [
        'foreignKey' => 'type_id'
    ]);
```

To generate proper relations from `CLI` go to `'project_directory/bin'` in command promot and hit following bake command:

```
cake bake types model // for types table
```

and

```
cake bake jobs model // for jobs table
```

See details here : [CakePhp3 Code Generation With Bake](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/bake/usage.html)

Comment: i actually tryed this allready in several versions and didnt succeed and tryed again due to your advice. i cant figure it out what is wrong. still the same error.

Comment: try using bake command to generate proper relations as shown in updated answer.